# ASP.NET web page authenticate in Azure AD by request

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm developing a local ASP.NET web application with a custom login page to authenticate users in Azure AD. I whant to make a request to Azure AD passing the username/password and get the token/user_info to authenticate the user, without prompt the Azure AD login screen.

1. Somebody knows how can I make this request?
2. Is it possible?

I'm trying to use OpenID connect, OAuth, JWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

[image]

Use `ROPC`, you can send http request to get `access_token` and `id_token`.

[image]

[image]