# Appsettings from azure not accessible in the backend or frontend of my next js application

Tags: reactjs, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, next.js

I have a next js application that I want to host on azure app service. I've setup a dockerfile for running the application, which looks the following:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14.15.5-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
 
# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build:testing
 
# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
 
ENV NODE_ENV production
 
# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY --from=builder /app/next-i18next.config.js ./next-i18next.config.js
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
 
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
RUN chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/.next
USER nextjs
 
EXPOSE 3000
 
# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# RUN npx next telemetry disable
 
CMD ["yarn", "start:testing"]
```

The docker image is build and push to azure from bitbucket pipeline. The image is working fine and the push goes well. I am pushing using Microsofts own supplied code https://bitbucket.org/microsoft/azure-web-apps-containers-deploy/src/master/.

My issue lies in the appsettings set in the app service is not available in the application hosted on azure. I am trying to access the variables as environment variables as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux
but with no luck. The variable is just undefined. I've tried accessing both from client and serverside in next js (should only be available server side as far as I understand).

I have a staging and production deployment slot, which needs to change which backend to use, and I want to switch between them by swapping staging into production. One of the things that change when swapping is appsettings as far as I can see. I've checked that the variable I am trying to access is set in kudu.

To repeat the question: How do I access the appsettings variables in my next js applicaton?

Best
Drachon

PS. I made an error, and error with the deployment flow of docker. Now I can fetch the appsettings from the serverside of nextjs

Comment: You can't access app settings from front end. front end runs in browser not on the server side

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas's comment is right.

> You can't access app settings from front end. front end runs in browser not on the server side

Related Posts:

[1. I am unable to read environment variable from azure app service configuration from my REACT app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576612/i-am-unable-to-read-environment-variable-from-azure-app-service-configuration-fr/67578822#67578822)

[2. Azure WebApps React: the environment variables exist but are not present when I call process.env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045282/azure-webapps-react-the-environment-variables-exist-but-are-not-present-when-i/67052708#67052708)

[3. Azure app service externalize variables environment into my Angular web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586697/azure-app-service-externalize-variables-environment-into-my-angular-web-applicat/66651064#66651064)

## Workaround:

You can use restapi to get access the appsettings variables, not by using `process.env.Your_Parmas`

**Related post:** [Accessing Azure Application Settings with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856681/accessing-azure-application-settings-with-javascript/63916927#63916927)

**Official doc:** [Web Apps - List Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-application-settings)